# Get Outlook folders icons

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am building an add-in which requires selection of multiple outlook folders. For that purpose I created selection dialog that lists folders and allows user to select one or more by checking the check boxes next to tree view items.

I was hoping that somehow I could read/get the outlook folder icons from my add in code which is written in C# (any solution that works with outlook object model would do).

I was trying hard around MAPIFolder.GetCustomIcon but it returns null for all folders and when you read the documentation it is clear that it is not meant for this i.e. it returns value only if folder has custom icon and if it is not any of default folders.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.getcustomicon%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use an icon editing tool (like Axialis Icon Workshop) that can extract icon and image resources from related Outlook .dll and .exe files.  It's a real mess to figure out what icon is where there as they exist in small and large quantities in very many different files.

Comment: Thats pretty much my last option. But it looks its only option so far. Icons should be in outllibr.dll. I have some code to extract them from dll.